# Is there any way to access contributing modules instances from application component dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have created a small sample to test dagger2 implementation. I have created a utility class in which an Activity's instance is to be injected. Is there any way to get this utility class instance in Activity itself using dagger2

**CoreApplication.kt**

```
class CoreApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var dispatchingActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector    }

    val component: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .sharedPreference(AppConstants.FILE_NAME_SHARED_PREFERENCES)
                .build()
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
        component.sharedPref().saveString("hello", "world")
        Log.i("test", component.sharedPref().getString("hello"))

    }
}
```

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class, AppModuleBinds::class, AppModuleProvides::class))
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun sharedPreference(@Named(Constant.Name.SHARED_PREFERENCES) sharedPreferenceName: String): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

    fun inject(application: CoreApplication)

    fun sharedPref() : SharedPreferenceUtils

}
```

**ActivityBuilder.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder{
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(HomeModuleBinds::class))
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @PerActivity
    abstract fun dialogUtils() : DialogUtils

}
```

**HomeModuleBinds.kt**

```
@Module
    abstract class HomeModuleBinds {
        @Binds
        @PerActivity
        abstract fun activityContext(activity: Activity): Context

        @Binds
        @PerActivity
        abstract fun activity(activity: Activity): Activity
    }
```

**DialogUtils.kt**

```
@PerActivity
class DialogUtils @Inject constructor(var activity: Activity) {
    fun showDialog(error: String) = {
        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(error).create().show()

    }
}
```

Is there any way I can use DialogUtils instance in MainActivity Using dagger2 dependency cycle?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    @Singleton
    lateinit var sharedPref : SharedPreferenceUtils

    @Inject
    @PerActivity
    lateinit var dialogUtils: DialogUtils

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sharedPref.saveString("test", "val")
        Log.i("test", sharedPref.getString("test"))



        //dialogUtils.showDialog("hello")
    }
}
```

For example using inject for DaggerUtils on MainActivity is causing cyclic dependency error

Comment: Check out my answer, it's exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inject the Activity into the Utility class.

Then in your Activity call:

```
dialogUtils.showDialog( "hello", MyACtivity.this)
```

In dialogUtils:

```
fun showDialog(error: String, context: Context) = {
        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(error).create().show()

    }
```

Comment: I am exploring if there any way to get instance of ActivityBuilder class if I create instance of Some complicated Object at PerActivity Scope and need to access this object in the activity itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can use DialogUtils instance in MainActivity Using dagger2 dependency cycle?

Yes, there is. To do that, you'll have to do the following changes in your Dagger setup:

**1. ActivityBuilder.kt**

Delete the following lines:

```
@PerActivity
abstract fun dialogUtils() : DialogUtils
```

Why? You don't need it. You already have **DialogUtils** injectable, since you annotated the class itself with `@PerActivity` and the constructor with `@Inject`. Dagger will automagically do the required binding wherever `DialogUtils` is needed. You write provide/bind methods only when you're injecting an abstract type. In this case, `DialogUtils` is not implementing an abstract type that you inject in the `Activity`. You inject the actual implementation directly so you don't need to setup any bindings.

**2. HomeModuleBinds.kt**

Change the Activity binding to more the specific `Activity` you want to bind to `Activity`, in this case it's `MainActivity`. Dagger will then understand that it needs to bind it to `Activity` when **DialogUtils** asks for it. You will need to do that for each `Activity` you want to use **DialogUtils** in the `Activity`'s own module - the one you pass as an argument to the `@ContributeAndroidInjector(modules = [...])`, in this case it is **HomeModuleBinds.kt**.

```
@Binds
@PerActivity
abstract fun bindMainActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): Activity
```

**3. DialogUtils**

The way you have method `showDialog(String)` defined currently, it returns a lambda! Remove the equals `=`.

```
fun showDialog(error: String) {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(error).create().show()

}
```

**4. MainActivity.kt**

Remove the scope annotations from the injected fields.

```
@Inject
@Singleton // <-- Remove this
lateinit var sharedPref : SharedPreferenceUtils

@Inject
@PerActivity // <-- Remove this
lateinit var dialogUtils: DialogUtils
```

You can only annotate Components, Provide/Bind methods and classes with scope annotations!